# Can I receive email for multiple domains using a single email server?

Tags: domains, dns, email

I have multiple domains in the form of `abcd.com`, `abcd.it`, `abcd.eu`, etc... My main mail server is set for `abcd.com` so all my emails are in the form of `name@abcd.com`

Now I would like to know if I can receive the emails coming from `name@abcd.it` on my `@abcd.com` domain with the correct configuration of MX records on the DNS Server.

Is this possible, or does every domain need their own email server?

Answer (score 4):

It is very common for one mail server to handle the email for several (or even thousands of domains).  When you buy hosted email services, you point your MX records to their email server.  Your email gets handled by the same server as their other customers.

Most email servers can be set up for multiple domains.  Here are some articles that walk you through the details for various ones:

- [Setup Postfix for multiple domains - Experiencing Technology](https://blog.tinned-software.net/setup-postfix-for-multiple-domains/)
- [How to have exim on server with multiple domains send each mail from its own domain, not the server hostname?](https://serverfault.com/questions/759489/how-to-have-exim-on-server-with-multiple-domains-send-each-mail-from-its-own-dom)
- [Multi Domain Setup - Zimbra Forums](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=63414)

Comment: Just to be clear, it's also possible to set up your mail server to route all mail for multiple domains into a single mailbox, so `@abcd.it` will be picked up on `@abcd.com`